# The outputs of ps and top do not match

Tags: linux, script, grep, perl, top

I have a situation where I have a process, say `script.pl` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483928/simple-perl-socket-script-hanging?noredirect=1#comment23657045_16483928) it is), which seems to stick around in the output to `ps auxw | grep script.pl`, sometimes when load is heavy it sticks around for several minutes.  This script is called 5-10 times a second by another process (this process does a nonblocking call to the script like this: `System(/some/path/script.pl &)`).

At first I was worried that this script was for some reason failing to complete in a timely fashion and thus slowing other things down.  However, all the script does is write a message to another box via a TCP socket.

And that's where things get weird.  1) I can verify this socket operation (the only thing the script does) completes by viewing the logs on the other box -- it gets the message immediately and on time. 2) Even though I see many instances of (seemingly completed) `script.pl` instances in `ps` output, I do not see corresponding entries if I do something like `top -n 1 | grep script.pl` -- this seems to indicate `script.pl` isn't using any resources; in fact there are no instances at all of `script.pl` in this output.

So finally, are there any known issues with `ps` or the Perl interpreter that could lead to completed Perl scripts hanging around in `ps` output, but not `top` output?

Thanks!

EDIT: I changed the top command call to: `top -n 1 -u script_pl_user | grep script.pl`.  Now the process shows up equally in both places.  However, in `top`, it's showing CPU usage of 0.0% and no or very very very small memory usage.  Why is script.pl sticking around even though its operations are verified to be completed?

Comment: `top` shows only `n` processes, where `n` depends on the terminal size. By default it's ordered by CPU usage, so you won't see processes which don't use the CPU too much. So why do you expect your script should be listed in this (truncated) top list? `ps ax` shows all processes.

Comment: Yes.  I've changed my top call to `top -n 1 -u script_pl_user | grep script.pl`.  My main question remains, why is script.pl still showing up in `top` and `ps` even though the operation it was supposed to do is verified to be completed?  Why are they sticking around?

Comment: [Top and ps not showing the same cpu result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/top-and-ps-not-showing-the-same-cpu-result)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the mechanics of ps and top.

Top simply aggregates usage by PID, and the System call in Perl essentially uses the OS' native fork(), which creates a child process.  Child processes have the same PID as the parent.  ps enumerates all running processes.  For instance, note that the same thing is true of Apache.  If you do Top and find Apache, you'll see only one entry, but if you do a ps aux and find Apache in there, there are several entries with the same PID.

Really, top is meant to find the total resource usage of a program, so you don't want to see the amount each child is using, and ps is to find what programs are running, in detail, so you want to see all of the child processes.

Comment: Any idea why a process continues to show up for ps or top when the operation it was to complete is verified completed?  Is it an issue maybe with the actual Perl binary doing the interpretation?  Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608058/perl-fork-exec-child-process-gone-wild) is a link to what I suspect is going on.  For some reason, I think that you're creating "zombies" because your child processes are not correctly terminating.  This is an error in your Perl, not in the interpreter. I really don't know much Perl, so I can't give you much more than that, hopefully that link is helpful to you.